# RegExp and MatchResult in GWT returns only first match

Tags: java, regex, string, gwt

I am trying to use RegExp and MatchResult in GWT. It returns only first occurrence  in a word. I need to have all the three "g", "i", "m". I tried "gim" which is global, multiline and case insensitive. But it is not working. Please find the code below. Thanks in advance.

The expected output is, it should find 3 matches of "on" in "On Condition" irrespective of the case.

```
import com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.MatchResult;
import com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.RegExp;

public class PatternMatchingInGxt {

public static final String dtoValue = "On Condition";
public static final String searchTerm = "on";

public static void main(String args[]){
    String newDtoData = null;
    RegExp regExp = RegExp.compile(searchTerm, "mgi");
    if(dtoValue != null){
        MatchResult matcher = regExp.exec(dtoValue);
        boolean matchFound = matcher != null;
        if (matchFound) {
            for (int i = 0; i < matcher.getGroupCount(); i++) {
                String groupStr = matcher.getGroup(i);
                newDtoData = matcher.getInput().replaceAll(groupStr, ""+i);
                System.out.println(newDtoData);
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to fix it this way: `String newDtoData = DtoValue;`

and

`MatchResult matcher = regExp.exec(dtoValue);
while (matcher != null) {
  newDtoData = newDtoData.replaceFirst(RegExp.quote(matcher.getGroup()), ""+i); 
  System.out.println(newDtoData);
  matcher = regExp.exec(dtoValue);
}`

Comment: That works!. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to collect all matches, run `exec` until you get no match.

To replace multiple occurrences of the search term, use `RegExp#replace()` with a pattern *wrapped with a capturing group* (I could not make `$&` backreference to the whole match work in GWT).

Change the code as follows:

```
if(dtoValue != null){

    // Display all matches
    RegExp regExp = RegExp.compile(searchTerm, "gi");
    MatchResult matcher = regExp.exec(dtoValue);
    while (matcher != null) { 
        System.out.println(matcher.getGroup(0));  // print Match value (demo)
        matcher = regExp.exec(dtoValue); 
    }

    // Wrap all searchTerm occurrences with 1 and 0
    RegExp regExp1 = RegExp.compile("(" + searchTerm + ")", "gi");
    newDtoData = regExp1.replace(dtoValue, "1$10");
    System.out.println(newDtoData);
    // => 1On0 C1on0diti1on0
}
```

Note that `m` (multiline modifier) only affects `^` and `$` in the pattern, thus, you do not need it here.

Comment: matcher does not have a getGroup(). So, I have added a for loop and modified the code as matcher.getGroup(i)

Comment: Then you just need to access Group 0 by passing `0` to it. You do not need any loop since the pattern has no capturing groups, i.e. the match data object has only one single group. Please check the `matcher.getGroup(0)`.

Comment: You are the one! I modified as you said. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew - I have a small glitch. I am getting the output as "1On0 C11on00dition" instead of "1On0 C1on0diti1on0". The text "on" should be prefixed by 1 and suffixed by 0

Comment: While I was checking my computer crashed. While I'm trying to reboot, please let me know if a simple replace here would be an option. Or do you need to get it in the loop?

Comment: Anything that gives me​ the desired output. I want to replace all the occurrences. Thank you so much.

Comment: See my  updated answer. The regex will work [like this](https://regex101.com/r/5mKAkK/1). `$&` is the backreference to the whole match value.

Comment: @Kutty: Still having any issues? Please let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Stribizew - It is getting prefixed. But suffix is not working. "1On C1onditi1on" is the output that i got after executing your code. Thank you so much

Comment: It is strange because the replacement is `1`, the [whole match inserted with `$&`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.html#replace-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and then a literal `0`. Try using `1$00` or `1$000` or `1${0}1` as replacement patterns.

Comment: Yes, just tried lots of variations but to no avail. Use `$1` backreference, `$&` does not work.